# SQL agent SSIS scheduled interval job acting weird

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a SSIS package which is responsible to load the data for midnight to current hour on an hourly basis. At every hour the target table truncated and loads the data from midnight to current hour. The data is populated by a stored procedure and the job is scheduled to execute on an hourly interval. Sometimes the data is not transfer correctly even the successful execution of the package.
Some time it add the duplicate records despite no change in the query , The data is corrected in next hour execution. What could be the potential area to lookup for this intermittent issue .
Currently we have only audit table and from that we only got to know that either half of the records are transfer or duplicate entries occurred. Is this because job is scheduled via SQL agent ?

It is really frustrating as we have no trace to dig it up , what kind of logging will help for this issue?

**UPDATE :**
We have found out that the issue was occurring due to the READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level in stored procedure. Regarding this observation i have a question that we have had a issue of 0 records populated in target table , Can this happen with the READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level? Can READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level returned zero records sometimes?

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you but have you thought of creating a history table and creating a trigger on the table you are working on. That way you can capture events like insert update and delete on that table. It definitely won't give you the answer to the problem but might uncover where you can start to look.

Comment: Can you share the package layout?